# Grub-rescue due to grub deleted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I accidentally deleted grub's partition after formatting my USB (BAD TIMING) and I can't do anything now...

I don't have a live USB, and all partitions are NTFS.

I have Windows 7 installed, I can't use any other computers, so no live USBs. [CORRECTION: SEE UPDATE AT END OF POST]

I know windows 7 has a bootloader, and I want to use rescue to load win7's bootloader into memory and jump to it, but I can't figure out how to do that.

The only ext4 partition was formatted, I can't even do INSMOD NORMAL.

LS says:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

SET says:

```
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos5
```

I need to fix it very fast for work reasons.

If I left out any crucial details tell me ASAP

Please send help.

**UPDATE**: I just remembered I still have my old, semi-busted computer! I hope I can do this.

**UPDATE**: my old computer doesn't have a working keyboard and can't use USB ones. NOOOOO

**UPDATE**: I can access my BIOS now... but not helpful.

```
Action Setup Utility Copyright (C) 2008 American Megatrends, Inc.
```

**UPDATE**: should I use my sister's old computer that is very busted?

Comment: Please try to get a live USB and do a grub rescue. That is the only viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu, I also formatted the ext4 partition and then I was stuck with grub rescue for 2 days. I think you also did the same thing. And now, without boot partition, you don`t have the necessary files to boot with insmod normal. I had no other option but to boot from windows 7 installation media disk (Note- you can use any windows 7,8,8.1,10 installation media disk, let it be a CD or USB. Ask a friend whether they have installation media disk available or not. You just need to somehow get to use the cmd) and fix the bootloader. Visit this [link](https://neosmart.net/wiki/no-such-partition-grub-rescue/#Fix_Error_no_such_partition_Grub_rescue_in_Windows_XP_7) for the steps for rescue.

Please let me know whether this helped or not.